# GDI: Check if loaded image is a valid jpg

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

i'm loading a jpg-file with CreateBitmapFromFile().

It always returns "2" if it's an image.

But how can i check that it's an valid jpg-file (not a gif, pdf or whatever)?

Thanks!
Roman

Answer (score 0):

If you use Image.FromFile instead, you can get the RawFormat of the image.  It's possible that you lose the raw format once you create a Bitmap object, since now it is a bitmap.

```
var file_image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\Sourcefile.jpg");
var file_image_format = file_image.RawFormat;
```